# How to get email domains

Tags: php, html

**DATABASE:** 
firstmail@***gmail***.com 
secondmail@***gmail***.com 
thirdmail@***yahoo***.com 
fourthmail@***hotmail***.com 
fifthmail@***yahoo***.com

**QUESTION:** 
I made function that will take only email domain [gmail, yahoo, etc] but it saves in variable only last email domain, but i need it to save all domains in one variable but cant save 2 equal domains...

**EXAMPLE:** 
***In database***: 
firstmail@***gmail***.com 
secondmail@***gmail***.com 
thirdmail@***yahoo***.com 
fourthmail@***hotmail***.com 
fifthmail@***yahoo***.com

***In variable***: 
gmail 
yahoo 
hotmail

**CODE:**

```
        $subscriptions_emails = Subscription::select('email')->get()->toArray();

        foreach ($subscriptions_emails as $domains){
            $full_email = implode (',', $domains);  // test@gmail.com
            $email_split_dot= explode(".", $full_email);  // 0 = test@gmail   1 = com 
            $email_without_after_dot = $email_split_dot[0];  // test@gmail
            $email_split_at_symbol = explode("@", $email_without_after_dot);  // 0 = test   1 = gmail
            $email_domain = $email_split_at_symbol[1]; // gmail
        }

        dd($email_domain);
```

Comment: What is the problem you have? You can use arrays and append any value with code like `$domains[] = $email_domain;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use an array to help collecting domain names like:

```
$domains = array();    
foreach ($subscriptions_emails as $domains){
    
            $full_email = implode (',', $domains);
    
            $email_split_dot= explode(".", $full_email);  
     
            $email_without_after_dot = $email_split_dot[0];  
    
            $email_split_at_symbol = explode("@", $email_without_after_dot);  
    
            $email_domain = $email_split_at_symbol[1];
            
             if(!in_array($email_domain, $domains, true)){ //check if not already exist
                  array_push($domains, $email_domain);
                }
 
        }
     var_dump($domains);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but you should change:
$domains = array(); to $domains_array = array(). same in array_push so others can use this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression also:

```
$email_domains = array();
foreach($emails as $email){
 preg_match('/@([^.]+)\./', $email, $domain);
 $email_domains[$domain[1]] = $domain[1];
}
```

Explanation of regex:

```
@       look for an @ followed by
([^.]+) look for one or more characters that arent
        a point and put it in a subpattern followed by
\.      look for a point
```